# Media from media library getting detached

Tags: media-library

**Sitecore version**: 9.0.2 Scaled

**What is happening**: 
No image or media file has been changed. But the images from a folder in the media library stopped getting rendered on the site.

Upon investigation, we have noticed that the media seems detached from the Sitecore in Web database. The same can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The URL of the image is forming like this: https://site.com/-/media/images_jf2/destination-attraction-icons/london.svg?la=en&hash=8B1666EABE5ACF31A0D01512AC4198EA

Please help me to understand why this is happening and what remedy I should take.

Edit 1:

Image showing raw value:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103149/discussion-on-question-by-nutsandbolts-media-from-media-library-getting-detached).